# CSS reset overrides specified elements in Firefox

Tags: css, css-reset

I have a stylesheet where I apply a reset in the beginning. This sets the margin and padding to 0, among other things, for a slew of tags. However, later in the stylesheet I apply margins and padding to specific tags. Yet for some reason Firefox isn't getting past the reset at very specific places points.

Here's an example of what's happening. Below is my reset:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Here is a line I added to provide style to a specific `div` element with class `modified`:

```
.modified { padding-top: 5px; align:center; }
```

In Safari, when I inspect that specific `div`, I see the line I created in my stylesheet and that appears to be applied.

In Firefox, when I use firebug on that same `div`, I see only my css reset code.

Is there a way around this? I've tried `!important`, as well as re-naming it `div.modified` instead of just `modified` but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + F5 to clear cache?

Comment: Align is deprecated. http://jsfiddle.net/BucTW/ seems to work fine in terms of the CSS being applied.

Comment: @tvalent, please post a URL. Does the actual code contain the `align` property (which does not belong to CSS) or something else in place of it?

Comment: Yep, clearing the cache didn't do anything. Maybe it's being affected elsewhere outside of that element.

Comment: I just have it locally. And yes it does contain `align`, which I'll change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` is not a valid CSS property. I'm assuming you were looking for `text-align: center`.

Obviously, something else is affecting it, as it all shows perfectly fine in my Firebug:

[image: exists]

Comment: True, but that wouldn't stop `padding-top: 5px` from showing up in Firebug.

Comment: @thirtydot: It shows up fine for me.

Comment: The question says "In Firefox, when I use firebug on that same div, I see only my css reset code.". If the only problem was that `align` is not a CSS property, then he wouldn't have wrote that sentence, because `padding-top: 5px` would show up in addition to his CSS reset when he inspects the element.

Comment: @thirtydot: And I'm in Firefox, **it shows for me**.

Comment: Exactly, it shows up. Until you added the "obviously, something else is affecting it" part, your answer didn't make sense. It doesn't show up for him so yes, obviously something other than `align` is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

That sure is weird. There is no conceivable reason that FF should be doing that. Have you tried modifying your reset (like, try adding background:yellow;) and see if that affects FF? Or you could try removing your reset and see if your .modified declaration kicks in. Just thoughts on how to at least narrow down what is the problem - is it the reset, or the second declaration? I'd also make sure your markup is valid - I've noticed that some browsers are more forgiving for malformed markup than others.

Comment: So changing to background yellow did something interesting: whereas the entire body background became yellow in firefox, only specific parts of safari turned yellow, not the entire body. So the issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm - at this point, I'd need to see all of the markup and CSS. Sometimes I will literally delete half of my stylesheet at a time to narrow down where problematic CSS is - then delete half of the problem half, etc until I find the particular rules that are causing issues.